# Listen to new messages from external discord

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, telegram

I have a little nodeJS App and I want to listen to new messages from an external discord that I don’t own.
I have a classic account on this discord.
Is there a way to detect new messages from this discord and do some treatment when it does ?

If it’s not possible, same thing with Telegram ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Discord it is not possible.
But for Telegram, I used this code and it works perfectly :

[Node js pass parameter to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67937453/node-js-pass-parameter-to-function)